# Reset rotated camera to be behind player again

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, camera, rotation

I am working on a 3rd person orbit camera which is following the player.

I successfully can stick a camera to the player and can also rotate the camera around the player with `Mouse X`.

Since 3 hours I am struggling with resetting the camera (on right-mouse click) to be exactly behind the player (showing his back) again after the player moved and rotated a bit around in the world and the camera circled around him.

Thanks for the help!

```
    Vector3 defaultOffset; // offset on scene start
    Vector3 offset;  // offset when camera is rotated by Mouse X

    void Start() {
        defaultOffset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
        offset = defaultOffset;
    }

    void LateUpdate() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) {
            // reset offset vector to be behind 
            // player on right-mouse button click
            // ??? HOW ???
        } else {
            // take movement of Mouse axis to rotate around the player
            float degrees = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 0.5 * Time.deltaTime;
            Quaternion angle = Quaternion.AngleAxis(degrees, Vector3.up);
            offset = angle * offset;
        }

        // set camera position and look at player
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
        transform.LookAt(player.transform);
    }
```

Comment: Try following : transform.position = player.transform.position.  If this doesn't work then the origin is the top/left corner of the object.  So the center if 1/2 the height and 1/2 the width from the corner.  To get center x += player.Left + (.5 * player.Width) y = player.Top += (.5 * player.Height)  camera.Left = x - (.5 * camera.Width) camera.Top = y - (.5 * camera.Height)  Remember y direction positive is down.

Comment: That does not work. I need to align my camera vector to the forward looking direction of the player but don’t know how.

Comment: I would like to snap back the camera to sit behind the player again after it was rotated to be for example on the right side of the player.

Comment: What is wrong with `offset=defaultOffset;`?

Comment: offset=defaultOffset does not take into account that the player may have rotated his upper body into a different direction after a while. The X & Z values of the offset need to be adjusted to be behind the player again. I have a feeling that it has something to-do with the players forward vector but all my tests failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
transform.position = player.position - player.forward * 2.5f;
```

I think this might work.

Comment: It works! I just need to add some smoothing and reposition the camera on the Y-axis but then it is all good. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, happy to be helpful.